# Move MySites to a new content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration

I have an environment that uses a single content database for both team sites, and mysites. We are in the process of upgrading from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010, and it seems like a good time to move the mysites to their own content db. The problem is finding the best method for moving the sites. My thought is to create a new content database in the current web application, use Move-SPSite to move the mysites to the new content database. Then un-mount/mount the newly created content database to the web application hosting the mysites.

is this the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use Move-SPSite for each MySite and the MySite Host (if applicable), then detach the old content database (if applicable).

Comment: worked perfectly